# How to convert a boolean function to CNF?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, boolean-algebra, conjunctive-normal-form

Consider the boolean function:
$$f (x, y, z) = (x + \overline y) (y + \overline z) (z + \overline x)$$

I have converted it to DNF which is $xyz + \overline y \,\overline z \,\overline x$, but I have problem with converting it to CNF.

I have no clue at all how to solve this problem. Any help would be very much appreciated. :)

Comment: Convert $\neg f(x, y, z)$ to DNF. Then, negate both sides to get a formula for $f(x, y, z)$ in CNF using De Morgan.

Comment: What's the definition of CNF?

Comment: It's already in CNF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write the truth table for it.

\begin{matrix}
x & y & z & f(x,y,z)\\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{matrix}
Then read the one NF from the $1$ rows:
$$
f(x,y,z) \quad\Longleftrightarrow\quad xyz + \overline{x}\,\overline{y}\,\overline{z}
$$
and read the other NF from the $0$ rows
$$
f(x,y,z)\quad\Longleftrightarrow\quad
(\overline{x}+\overline{y}+z)(\overline{x}+y+\overline{z})(\overline{x}+y+z)
(x+\overline{y}+\overline{z})(x+\overline{y}+z)(x+y+\overline{z})
$$

In general, there is no "short" way to compute CNF.  [The problem is NP hard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form#Computational_complexity).